# Filtering per column with button angular material table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to have a filter button on the column headers whereby I can filter the results by clicking a checkbox, as well as multiple column filtering.

This is what I've tried, the button loads the menu, but when clicked also starts the sorting, and the positioning isn't right:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="source" matSort (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event)"
 matRipple [matRippleRadius]="'15'"
 [matRippleColor]="'#03a9f4'">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
        <mat-icon>filter_list</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-menu #menu>
          <ng-template matMenuContent>
            <div *ngFor="let item of items">
                <mat-checkbox class="mat-menu-item">{{item.name}}</mat-checkbox>  
            </div>
          </ng-template>
        </mat-menu>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Email Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="emailAddress">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Email Address </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.emailAddress}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns; sticky: true"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator [length]="source.length" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Here is an example of what I want:
[image: example]

Comment: Have you taken a look at: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-getting-started/#enable-sorting-and-filtering

Comment: I took a look, but I am working with a material angular table, that appears to be something completely different.

Comment: Got a bit closer, but still having issues

Comment: The stop propagation comment is the first step, after that it is all about doing stuff in your function to make the little sort modal pop up and sort the table as expected. you can pass into a mat-dialog a viewchild of the filter in question, and position based on that

Comment: code for ref:



const rect = this.triggerElementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      matDialogConfig.position = { left: `${rect.left > 300 ? rect.left - 200: 100}px`, top: `${rect.bottom + 50}px` };
      this.dialogRef.updatePosition(matDialogConfig.position);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a click event to your filter button to prevent sorting?

```
(click)="foo($event)"

foo($event: Event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
}
```